# JavaScript (Ajax) is not showing php response

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I've used an HTML form to post via JavaScript to a php file, now I need the response to be shown on the same HTML page. I've checked in firebug and I can see the correct response, however the JavaScript isn't showing it on the page.

HTML

```
        <fieldset>

        <legend>Search</legend>

        <div class="form-group">

          <input id="search-form" name="search" type="text" placeholder="Start searching here..." class="form-control input-md">
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" id="searchButton" onclick="searchForm()">Search</button>
        </div>

        </fieldset>
        </div>

        <div id="searchname">
        </div>
        <div id="searchbarcode">
        </div>
        <div id="searchserial">
        </div>
```

JavaScript

```
function searchForm(){

   var form = $(this);
   var url = 'http://localhost/search/search.php';
   var data = $("#search-form").val();

   $.post(url, data)
   .done(function(response){

        if(response.success)
        {
              var name = response.data.name;
              var barcode = response.data.barcode;
              var serial = response.data.serial;

              $("#searchname").html(name);
              $("#searchbarcode").html(barcode);
              $("#searchserial").html(serial);
        }
        else
        {


        }

   });
}
```

PHP

```
<?php
mysql_connect ("localhost", "root","")  or die (mysql_error());
mysql_select_db ("dissertation");
$search = isset($_POST['search']) ? $_POST['search'] : '';

$sql = mysql_query("select * from asset where 
                         name like '%$search%' or 
                         barcode like '%$search%' or
                         serial like '%$search%' ");

$num = mysql_num_rows($sql);


$json = array();
if($num > 0)
{

    $json['success'] = TRUE;
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){  
      $json['data']['name'] = $row['name'];
      $json['data']['barcode'] = $row['barcode'];
      $json['data']['serial'] = $row['serial'];
    }
}
else
{
    $json['success'] = FALSE;
}

echo json_encode($json);
?>
```

Comment: In the while loop, you are overwriting the array values each time – makes little sense if you have more than one result, and if there can only ever be one, then using a loop does not makes sense. As for why the rest of it is not working as expected – you’ll have to do a little debugging yourself, f.e. log the values you are trying to access to console.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you are passing wrong parameter in your ajax

it should be like

```
data = {search: $("#search-form").val()};
```